# Apache ignite takes a long time to create new cache

Tags: ignite

My application will create new cache on demand, but it seems Apache Ignite always takes seconds of time to create a new cache when there are hundreds of caches already. I find there are two stages
consuming most of the time when creating new cache :
stage1: Waiting in exchange queue
stage2: Waiting for full message
Is there any way I can optimize this process?

Apache ignige: 2.10.0, cluster mode, two nodes, jdbc thin client
Jvm: Java HotSpot(TM) 64 bit Server VM, 1.8.0_60

Answer (score 0):

- Cache creation operation is not cheap as you correctly highlighted, it is cluster-wide operation and requires PME and other internal routines. For that reasons, think of reusing the existing caches if you need best performance.
- You can accelerate caches processing and reduce resource usage if you group them in a single [Cache Group](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/cache-groups). But network communication will be required nevertheless.